# Is it possible to reference already defined field value during object definition?

Tags: javascript, object, syntax, definition

```
const message = {
  from: "abc",
  to: this.from,
}

console.log(message)
```

The above is extremely simplified version, where `from` was obtained through expensive `asyn` function call, and `to` is actually in form of `is_to_exist ? use_to : use_from`.

Is it possible to avoid doing the expensive `asyn` function call to obtain `from` again in `to` assignment, and use the already defined `from` value here?

Comment: `this` does not work because it does not point to `message`. Can you not use a local variable to store the result first and then reference the variable during object creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to use a temporary local variable, e.g.

```
const from = await someExpensiveFunction();

const message = {
    from,
    to: is_to_exist ? use_to : from,
};

console.log(message);
```

Comment: I thought that this is the only way, thanks for confirmation.